# How to make module css works with typescript in a gatsby application?

Tags: css, typescript, gatsby

I have an GastbyJS application, and I'm trying to add typescript on it. I solve most of the issues, but I'm not able to make the css module work with it.

I have this import in my file, that works fine:
`import styles from "./card.module.css"`

But when I added the typescript config it says that `Cannot find module './card.module.css'.ts(2307)`

I tried to use some gatsby plugins, but they didn`t work as expected.

The whole code is here: [github](https://github.com/astroregulus/regulus-site/blob/master/src/components/card.tsx)

Comment: Maybe you can add `gatsby-plugin-typescript` inside tsconfig.json plugins.

Comment: what version of gatsby are you using?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and after trying all the various plugins I came across this solution which worked for me.

Create a css.d.ts file with:

```
declare module '*.css' {
    const content: { [className: string]: string };
    export default content;
}
```

Add these lines to your tsconfig.json file:

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
"files": ["./src/typings/css.d.ts"]
```

The "files" path needs to match where your type definition file is.

https://github.com/thetrevorharmon/gatsby-starter-typescript-sass/issues/1#issuecomment-436748732

Comment: What would be the equivalent procedure if you have a `.jsconfig` instead?